# Voltage and current rise in an Inductor

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

Suppose switch is closed at t = 0. Right after the switch is closed there will be the voltage rise from the ac source. As the voltage rises from the ac source there should be a corresponding rise in the current through an inductor during the first positive half cycle of an ac voltage, as there is also a change in voltage during the first positive half cycle of the voltage from the ac source.

Then why in the graph we see no change in current in the inductor during the first positive half cycle rise of ac voltage from the source?

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that graph is correct? It's not.

Comment: After t = 0 voltage rises. Current lags behind the voltage by 90 degrees. So whats wrong with the graph?

Comment: The current will always be >= 0

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of [one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/493186/6334) on EE.SE.